# unable to send email on docker container from port 465

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, smtp

I tried to send an email from port 465, it works well on IDEA. But when I deployed it on docker, the email send failed. The error message is:

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtpdm.aliyun.com, port: 465, response: -1
```

Then I tried to change the port to 25, the email sent success.
Change the smtp server seems nothing better.
How can I send mail from port 465 on docker container?

Comment: How do you run docker container? And did you map/forward port 465?

Comment: I tried, but it didn't work. thanks for comment.

Comment: Check if this port number is not blocked in your server or router

Comment: that is impossible, it works well on IDEA

Answer (score 0):

make sure that the port is available on the host machine and ports are mapped correctly when you start the docker image.  also, make sure that postfix is installed in your docker image and is active (`sudo postfix status` or `sudo systemctl status postfix`).
if both of theses conditions are met but it still don't work please also Try to set these values to:

- `smtp_tls_wrappermode = yes`
- `smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt`

in `/etc/postfix/main.cf` in the docker container.